# Prove that $(k+2)^\alpha \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{(1+i)^\alpha} \ge (k+1)^\alpha \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{(1+i)^\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

In this problem, I'm trying to prove that for any $\alpha\in[1/2,1]$, there exists a constant $K(\alpha)$ such that for any $k\geqslant K(\alpha)$, the inequality
$$(k+2)^\alpha\cdot\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{(1+i)^\alpha}}{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{(1+i)^\alpha}}\right)\geq (k+1)^\alpha$$
holds. I have numerically verified the statement in python and it seems to be true. But I cannot come up with rigorous proof. Thx!

Comment: Three suggestions.  Avoid using an overly complicated math expression as your title.  Simplify the desired inequality (it needs to appear in the body of your Question, even if you decide to keep it in the title).  Explain what motivates your interest in this inequality for sufficiently large $k$ (depending on $\alpha$).

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $[(k+1)^\alpha - k^\alpha]\sum_{i=1}^k (1+i)^{-\alpha} \ge 1$.

Comment: Note that this is actually false for $\alpha = 1/2$.